# OpenGL: share top level mip between two mipmap chains

Tags: opengl, mipmaps

I was wondering if it's possible for two mipmap chains to share the data for the top level mip.

My use case is the following. I have two environment maps with mipmapping. One is blurred, and one isn't. But the level 0 mip is the same for both.

If sharing the top level mip was possible, that would allow me to save a big chunk of memory.

[image]